# Sencha Grid Json Obtener datos

Tags: sencha-touch

Tengo este grid en Sencha

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al obtener la data me tira estos datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

claramente se ve que me trae el dato BR'TX'FIELDS'002 
necesitaria los datos de los padres , osea RECEPTION Y PAGO SERVICIO , y se me a echo imposible poner navegar hacia arriba, alguien me ilumina

if(dataIndex.data.c5!==undefined){

```
var id = Ext.id();
Ext.defer(function () {
    Ext.widget('button', {
        renderTo: id,
        width: 24,
        icon:'appresources/images/edit1.png',
        border:0,
        style:{backgroundColor: 'transparent'},
        height:24,
        listeners: {
            click: {
                fn: function (event, target) {

                    var lastCellUsed=Ext.getCmp('v_rulesConfig').lastCell;
                    var clickToShow= Ext.getCmp('v_rulesConfig').clickToOpen;
                    if(lastCellUsed!=cell){
                        clickToShow=true;
                        Ext.getCmp('v_rulesConfig').lastCell=cell;
                    }
                    if(clickToShow){
                        Ext.getCmp('panel_parametersEdition').show();
                        var ruleId = dataIndex.data["ext-53"];

                        global_ruleIdSelected = ruleId;

                        console.log(ruleId);
                        console.log('aca pase');
                        console.log(dataIndex);
                        console.log('aca pase');
                         //console.log(global_project);
                        //INVESTIGAR
                       // global_stateSelected =
                        //global_trxTypeSelected = ;

                        Ext.getCmp('v_rulesConfig').configEditParameters(ruleId);
                    }else{
                        Ext.getCmp('panel_parametersEdition').hide();
                    }
                    Ext.getCmp('v_rulesConfig').clickToOpen=!clickToShow;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}, 50);
return Ext.String.format('<div id="{0}"></div>', id);
```

Comment: Te aconsejo poner el código para entender mejor y ayudarte

Comment: editada  la publicación

Comment: puedes almacenar todos los datos en una variable y usar  $b =json_decode($tuvariable,true); luego usar foreach() para parsear el resultado